# How to deploy Storybook for React Native live

Tags: react-native, deployment, storybook

I am creating a React Native app and have integrated Storybook to create a component library. I want to share the component library with my teammates for testing purposes. How can I achieve this? since Storybook for react-native doesn't have any build script.

I have tried converting it into react-native-web, but the build fails when I try to start story book for react-native-web

Answer (score 0):

You should use some tools or configurations like [Turbo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs). Turbo is an incremental bundler and builds a system optimized for JavaScript and TypeScript, written in Rust. It also contains React Native too, by using `npx create-turbo@latest -e with-react-native-web` command you can create a repo which contains React Native components alongside a Storybook configuration.